# Angular9 post the data to API by form data with HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm using Angular9 and I want to post the data to API by form data with HttpClient

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' 
});

let data: FormData = new FormData();
data.append('userName', this.loginData.userName); 
data.append('password', this.loginData.password);

this.http.post(url, data, {headers: headers});
```

and the request will like this:

[image]

But I expected like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: form data is usually sent with `post`

Comment: Typescript usually highlights that one can't send a data payload along with a GET request. You should be told what's wrong by your text editor, or at the very least by the compiler.

Comment: @Eyeslandic this is my mistake, it is a post request. I already update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the code to simply

```typescript
this.http.post<any>(url, this.loginData);
```

Things to note:

1. I have changed `get` to `post`, for security
2. I have typecasted the response to `any` using `<any>`
3. I have removed the headers, angular will add appropriate headers for me

Comment: remove the header and it works. Thanks, @Owen Kelvin

Comment: but then how do you pass jwt? Interceptor?